# Is there any option for refering an android project?

Tags: android, dependencies, project

I have to create an android project but,it has some dependencies on another project in eclipse..
Is there any option for linking these two projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to set the project as library project.U can do this via right click the project then properties-->android then set is library checked.

And in which you want to use library project add library project.

thats all.I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can add dependencies to other projects via 'Configure Build Path' of a project. There you can add projects to your build path.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you were talking about Android projects. For them you should do what THelper suggested.